# In angular textbox default value did not display

Tags: angular

I am trying to display default value in my textbox. I assigned it, but it is not display inside the textbox

```
<input class="form-control" #lastaccesstime="ngModel"
  name="lastaccesstime" [readonly]="true" disabled [(ngModel)]="lostkey.lastcheckdate" />
```

this is my model.ts

```
export class ReportLostKeyModel {
lastcheckdate: '2021-06-10';
```

}

When I inspect it, it can see as text box value

[image]

but this value did not show inside the textbox
[image]

how can I set default value correctly

Comment: How does your component code look like (the code where your declare`lostkey`)? Your class syntax also seems to be incorrect. Shouldn't it be `lastcheckdate = '2021-06-10`?

Comment: @StefanK  lostkey: ReportLostKeyModel = new ReportLostKeyModel();

Comment: Then, doesn't changing `lastcheckdate: '2021-06-10'` to `lastcheckdate = '2021-06-10'` solve your issue?

Comment: How can a value be set when the disabled attribute is used? Try removing that and try setting the value in ngOnInit().

Comment: this is for only prototype. thanks